# stm32 multiple ADC redings error

Tags: c, adc

I'm using cubemx to initiate the project, the mcu I'm using is stm32L053C6. To that I have 2 sensors and 2 transistors connected to adc inputs. The code below shows how I get the input value, voltage, from the first temperature sensor. Then I use the same code for each value I want to read. The problem here is that the first value I read is always wrong, it gives me 2048, and it's 12 bits resolution, so...

I wonder how I can fix this?

```
//Start ADC reading
if(HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc) != HAL_OK){
  while(1) {}
}

//Wait for EOC (end of conversion)
while(!(hadc.Instance->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC)){}
//Read ADC value

//Repeat for all channels.  
while(!(hadc.Instance->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC)){}
experiments[0+index].temperature += hadc.Instance->DR;
printf("\n ex0 i rolling %d\n", experiments[0+index].temperature);
```

The code for reading the voltage values for the 2 temperature sensors and transistors is as below. I read the values 16 times and calculate an average. But as I said the first value I read is 2048.

```
void readRollingADC(int index){
  HAL_Delay(1);

  //Start ADC reading
  if(HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc) != HAL_OK){
    while(1) {}
  }

  //Wait for EOC (end of conversion)
  while(!(hadc.Instance->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC)){}
  //Read ADC value

  *

> ****//Repeat for all channels.       while(!(hadc.Instance->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC)){}   experiments[0+index].temperature +=
> hadc.Instance->DR; printf("\n ex0 i rolling %d\n",
> experiments[0+index].temperature);****

* 

  while(!(hadc.Instance->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC)){}
  experiments[0+index].ube += hadc.Instance->DR;

  while(!(hadc.Instance->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC)){}
  experiments[0+index].vrb += hadc.Instance->DR;

  while(!(hadc.Instance->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC)){}
  experiments[0+index].vrc += hadc.Instance->DR;

  while(!(hadc.Instance->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC)){}
  experiments[1+index].temperature += hadc.Instance->DR;
printf("\n ex1 i rolling %d\n", experiments[1+index].temperature); 
  while(!(hadc.Instance->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC)){}
  experiments[1+index].ube += hadc.Instance->DR;

  while(!(hadc.Instance->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC)){}
  experiments[1+index].vrb += hadc.Instance->DR;

  while(!(hadc.Instance->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC)){}
  experiments[1+index].vrc += hadc.Instance->DR;

}
```

How do I fix this? Does it have something to do with the code or the initiation of the adc? What I can do is to read the first value and not save it, but I don't think that's the proper way :)

```
void MX_ADC_Init(void)
    {


        /**Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion) 
        */
      hadc.Instance = ADC1;
      hadc.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
      hadc.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV1;
      hadc.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
      hadc.Init.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;
      hadc.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DIRECTION_FORWARD;
      hadc.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
      hadc.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
      hadc.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
      hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
      hadc.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
      hadc.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
      hadc.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;
      hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = ENABLE;
      hadc.Init.LowPowerFrequencyMode = ENABLE;
      hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoPowerOff = ENABLE;
      HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc);

        sConfigAdc.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
        if(HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfigAdc) != HAL_OK){
            while(1){}
        }
            sConfigAdc.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
        if(HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfigAdc) != HAL_OK){
            while(1){}
        }

            sConfigAdc.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_2;
        if(HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfigAdc) != HAL_OK){
            while(1){}
        }

            sConfigAdc.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_3;
        if(HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfigAdc) != HAL_OK){
            while(1){}
        }

            sConfigAdc.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_5;
        if(HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfigAdc) != HAL_OK){
            while(1){}
        }
            sConfigAdc.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_6;
        if(HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfigAdc) != HAL_OK){
            while(1){}
        }
            sConfigAdc.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_7;
        if(HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfigAdc) != HAL_OK){
            while(1){}
        }

            sConfigAdc.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_8;
        if(HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfigAdc) != HAL_OK){
            while(1){}
        }
             /*
        sConfigAdc.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_9;
        if(HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfigAdc) != HAL_OK){
            while(1){}
        }  */


    }

    void HAL_ADC_MspInit(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
    {

      GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
      if(hadc->Instance==ADC1)
      {
      /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 0 */

      /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 0 */
        /* Peripheral clock enable */
        __HAL_RCC_ADC1_CLK_ENABLE();

        /**ADC GPIO Configuration    
        PA0     ------> ADC_IN0
        PA1     ------> ADC_IN1
        PA2     ------> ADC_IN2
        PA3     ------> ADC_IN3
        PA5     ------> ADC_IN5
        PA6     ------> ADC_IN6
        PA7     ------> ADC_IN7
        PB0     ------> ADC_IN8
        PB1     ------> ADC_IN9 
        */
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3 
                              |GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

      /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 1 */

      /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 1 */
      }
    }

    void HAL_ADC_MspDeInit(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
    {

      if(hadc->Instance==ADC1)
      {
      /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspDeInit 0 */

      /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspDeInit 0 */
        /* Peripheral clock disable */
        __HAL_RCC_ADC1_CLK_DISABLE();

        /**ADC GPIO Configuration    
        PA0     ------> ADC_IN0
        PA1     ------> ADC_IN1
        PA2     ------> ADC_IN2
        PA3     ------> ADC_IN3
        PA5     ------> ADC_IN5
        PA6     ------> ADC_IN6
        PA7     ------> ADC_IN7
        PB0     ------> ADC_IN8
        PB1     ------> ADC_IN9 
        */
        HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3 
                              |GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7);

        HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1);

      }
      /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspDeInit 1 */

      /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspDeInit 1 */
    } 

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    /* USER CODE END 1 */
```

The thing is, I want to read the values temp1, transistor_1 voltage (ube1, vrb1, vrc1), temp2 transistor_2 voltage (ube2, vrb2, vrc2)

16 times to get an average the code:

```
HAL_Delay(2);

  /* Set DAC at voltage level 1 (3.1v 0xF07)*/
  setDAC(0xF07);   // 
   printf("\n***************************\n");
  HAL_Delay(2);
  for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){ 

    readRollingADC(0); // read All inputs 16 times. 

void shiftAverages(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    experiments[i].temperature = (experiments[i].temperature >> 4);
    experiments[i].ube = (experiments[i].ube >> 4);
    experiments[i].vrb = (experiments[i].vrb >> 4);
    experiments[i].vrc = (experiments[i].vrc >> 4);
  }
}
```

I do these things for different setDAC values, and I enter the the function readRollingADC()
ut every time I enter the function the first read are always 2048 then it works fine.

it seems that somehow it gives me high when I read the first value, is that somthing that are automatically stored in the ADC register?

```
//Start ADC reading
  if(HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc) != HAL_OK){
    while(1) {}
  }

  //Wait for EOC (end of conversion)    
  while(!(hadc.Instance->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC)){}
  experiments[0+index].temperature += hadc.Instance->DR;
printf("\n ex0 i rolling %d\n", experiments[0+index].temperature); 
 HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc);
   HAL_Delay(20);
  HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc);
  HAL_Delay(20);

  while(!(hadc.Instance->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC)){}
  experiments[0+index].ube += hadc.Instance->DR;
   printf("\n ube si %d\n", experiments[0+index].ube); 
  HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc);
   HAL_Delay(20);
  HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc);
  HAL_Delay(20);
```

I did like this, bu this gives me tha same value for all channels, whas this what you ment or should I write somthing else?

Comment: How do you initialize hadc? ie. can you post `MX_ADC_Init()`?v Try: `HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc, HAL_MAX_DELAY); experiments[...].name = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);` ?

Comment: I have edited my first post now with adc_init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `hadc.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV` and `hadc.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE`. I guess you need to restart ADC after each channel is converted. So between each conversion you need to call `HAL_ADC_Stop` and then `HAL_ADC_Start`. You don't even clean ISR_EOC flag between conversions, you have to do that manually, that's why it's better to call `HAL_ADC_PollForConversions` to have it cleared. And you need to call `HAL_ADC_Start` exactly the same count as channels configured, ie. 9 in your setup, otherwise the ADC channel selection will miss the channel you expect to read.
With more then 5 channels I would recommend using DMA with a buffer of exactly the amount of words as channels configured and set `hadc.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV`. That way with a single `HAL_ADC_Start_DMA` you get all the channels bytes. With less then 5 channels, one regular channel + the rest injected channels with auto-injection do the job.
Remember to convert read ADC values with `__LL_ADC_CALC_TEMPERATURE` to temperature and with `__LL_ADC_CALC_DATA_TO_VOLTAGE` to voltages, from [stm32l0_ll_adc.h](https://github.com/Lora-net/LoRaMac-node/blob/master/src/boards/mcu/stm32/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/stm32l0xx_ll_adc.h).
You can read about stm32l0 hal drivers [here](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/41/78/8e/63/f9/32/44/12/DM00113898.pdf/files/DM00113898.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00113898.pdf).

Comment: I edited, the start and stop, but it gives me same value for every channel, so i think something is realy wrong :)

Comment: No, I dont know how to do that I'v Googled it but I dont find how?

Comment: It's ALL in HAL_ADC_PollForConversions function.... for example see [here](https://github.com/cnoviello/mastering-stm32/blob/master/nucleo-l073RZ/system/src/stm32l0xx/stm32l0xx_hal_adc.c#L993).